# Understanding @property attribute by comparing with auto generated code Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, xcode4, iboutlet

I have a few doubts regarding the use of attributes. By reading the ARC transition document, strong and weak should be used in place of retain and assign.

However there are at least two cases where Xcode auto generated code is doing something else. I would like to know if this is just a 'still not updated' tool from Xcode, or if I am missing something.

The first case is with Core Data managed object auto generation.

After having created the relevant classes, this is what appears in a .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *myProperty;
```

what is the compiler doing in this case? Replace `retain` with `strong`?

But the strangest case (for my lack of knowledge) is with `IBOutlet`, the auto generated code when connecting Interface Builder outlet with .h file is this:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myOutlet;
```

and again this seems different from the recommended 'weak' attributes. I mean recommended by users on various forum.

And this is added in `viewDidUnload:`

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setMyOutlet:nil];
}
```

why do we need this statement? Even though by running the profiler instruments there's no trace of memory leak or other memory issue? I mean, without setting to `nil` everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unsafe_unretained` will store an **unsafe** pointer, i.e. the pointer will still be there when your label goes away, but it'll point to some garbage. That's why the `-viewDidUnload` code resets that pointer to `nil` at that point. Using `weak` properties will automagically turn the pointer value into `nil` when the object it points to goes away. That's why it's recommended.

`retain` and `strong` are basically the same thing. The object is retained, i.e. will not go away until the property is set to another value (e.g. `nil`) at which point the object is released.

Comment: small addition: In ARC `unsafe_unretained` does the same thing as `assign` did in non-ARC. If you don't target iOS4 there is no real reason to use `unsafe_unretained` at all. This property specifier was introduced to allow ARC on iOS4.